# In Terminal how do you run a sudo command with an & at the end without prior authentication?

Tags: command-line

I have been using an `&` at the end of some commands, to free up the terminal. However, if it requires sudo, it doesn't work. I can get around this by running a random sudo command before it, but this is a pain, and I could also type the password in the command but this is insecure. Is there any alternative way of getting these commands to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially what you're doing , is putting command into background with `&`. There is a manual way to do so. Here's an example with `sudo apt-get update`

1. Run `sudo apt-get update` as usual, enter password.
2. As soon as command starts, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to pause the process
3. Run `bg` command to put the stopped job into background.

Notice that the output still will be displayed to `stdout`. If it is not essential, use `&> /dev/null` redirection appended to the command to hide the output.

Alternative way, would be to run the shell with sudo privilleges, and run commands with `-c` flag, like so:

```
sudo bash -c 'apt-get update &>/dev/null  & '
```

Comment: I think the 'alternative' way and the three step solution should be swapped. The 'alternative' solution seems much much cleaner, easier and less hacky to me. Other than that, great answer!